# Dynamic ng-click in Angular using regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, compilation

I have got a normal string like "Lorem #ipsum ..." where I want to replace all hashtags with span elements that can be clicked and pass their value to a function.

All hashtags are detected via a regex and the needed regex is added to the Array allregs which is than looped through and should replace the elements.

I was trying:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allregs.length; i++) {
  var regex = new RegExp(allregs[i], "g");
  var el = "<span class='hashtag' ng-click='goto(" + allregs[i] + ")'>" + allregs[i] + "</span>";
  var temp = $compile(el)($scope);
  html = html.replace(regex, temp);
};
return $sce.trustAsHtml( html );
```

The return is used inside 
`<span ng-bind-html="engine.trust(entry.content)"></span>` but it throws an error (Error: $parse:lexerr
Lexer Error)

It displays "Lorem [[object HTMLSpanElement]]" on the screen.
What can I do?

Comment: I don't fully understand what is going on with your app here. Is this a directive? Is this within the controller?  Could you show a little more about how you have this app constructed?

Comment: @JonBlack It is all inside the controller like `var app = new angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $sce, $compile) {
$scope.engine = {
trust: function( html ){
...
for (var i = 0; i < allregs.length; i++) {
...
};
return $sce.trustAsHtml( html );
},
...`

Comment: I would suggest that you turn this into a directive then.  Once you do that have it handle the regex directly.

Comment: @JonBlack Discovered the problem. allregs[i] is of type string so I had to change it to `ng-click='goto(\"" + allregs[i][0] + "\")'` Such a stupid mistake ;) But I followed your advice and turned it into a directive, thanks

Comment: Nice, I am glad it worked out for you.